# Why is the measure of this set $0$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let us have $f,g$ measurable functions in a measure space. We have the following set:

{$x: f(x) < y  < g(x)$}. Prove, that if the measure of this set is $0$ for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$, then the measure of {$ x: f(x) < g(x)$} set is $0$ too.

This question seems somehow trivial for me. If $f(x) < g(x)$, we can always find such $y$, that $f(x) < y < g(x)$, so the two sets must be equivalent, therefore the statement is proven.

Am I thinking something wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just because two sets are "equivalent", doesn't mean that they have the same measure.

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent" sets? The first set depends on $y$, whereas, the second set does not. (The second set is the union of the first sets over all $y$, though...)

Comment: Note that the first set should be labeled as $A_y$, because it depends on the fixed value $y$, while the second is the union of the first over all values of $y$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $x$ is such that $f(x) < g(x)$, then there exists a *rational* $y$ such that $f(x) < y < g(x)$.  Now, consider the appropriate countable union.

Comment: Wow, amazing hint, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, thanks. :)